# A couple of issues with drag + drop

Tags: javascript, html

I have something like the attached code where some green divs can be dragged and dropped between list elements.

There are 2 issues that I don't seem to be able to solve:

1) The "ghost" dragged image in the larger "Take Me" div is almost invisible. The user has very little idea of what is been dragged. Can this be changed somehow ?

2) The drop target is the one under the mouse pointer. This is quite logical but it makes it difficult for the user to understand where the green is going to be dropped. If it was dragged by the bottom then the green makes a big jump down when the mouse button is released. Is there a way to make the top of the ghost image snap to the pointer ?

In the final application there will be many green divs and the user should be able to slot them together with no overlap so a clear idea of what is being dragged and precision dropping are important.

Would I be better off not using the drag events and implement dragdrop manually the old-fashioned way (most likely using some kind of library) ?

I need support only for the latest browsers and have tried only Chrome and FF on Windows so far.

```js
function initDragDrop(){

    initDragDrop.dragged = null;

    // Dragged
    $('div')
        .on('dragstart',
            function(event) {

                initDragDrop.dragged = this;
                initDragDrop.dragged.style.opacity = 0.5;
                event.originalEvent.dataTransfer.setData('text/plain', 'dummy'); 
            })
        .on('dragend', function( event ) {

            event.target.style.opacity = '';
        });
        
    // Drop targets
    $('li')
        .on('dragenter', function(event) {

            event.preventDefault(); 
        })
        .on('drop dragdrop', function(event){

            event.preventDefault(); 
            event.stopPropagation();

            event.target.classList.remove('dragover');
            if ( initDragDrop.dragged ) {

                initDragDrop.dragged.style.opacity = '';
                $(this).append($(initDragDrop.dragged));
                initDragDrop.dragged = null;
            }
        })
        .on('dragover', function(event) {

            event.target.classList.add('dragover');
            event.preventDefault(); 
        })
        .on('dragleave', function(event) {

            event.target.classList.remove('dragover');
        });
}

initDragDrop();
```

```css
ul {
  width: 30em;
  display: block;
}
ul.small {
  margin-top: 4em;
  width: 10em;
}
li {
  height: 2em;
  border: 1px solid grey;
}
li.dragover {
  background: #ddd;
}
div {
  background-color: lightgreen;
  border: 2px solid darkgreen;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
  width: 90%;
  height: 5em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
<li></li>
<li></li>
<li><div draggable="true">
Take Me
</div></li>
<li></li>
</ul>
<ul class="small">
<li></li>
<li></li>
<li><div draggable="true">
Take Me too
</div></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: check this 

http://www.htmldrive.net/items/show/783/Cool-Drag-and-Drop-table-content

Comment: for the almost invisible drag ghost image: you can maybe have a look at this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DataTransfer/setDragImage . You can set a dragimage which will be easier to see.

Comment: @mrdeadsven, thanks. That looks halfway there. Problem is that my draggables are going to be of variable widths, heights, color and content. I could make something that delivers a properly sized image but it looks more work than other solutions.

Comment: @jigarhalani I'll have look at that.

Comment: yes that is correct, it was more of a last resort solution, also could you explain your second problem a bit more to me because I think I'm understanding it incorrect. The way you describe it, it sounds to me that when you drag the item you just want a clear indicator of where it is going to be dropped. But I don't think this is what you mean since that would be easily solved if for example you would change your css from li.dragover {background: #ddd;} to li.dragover {background: "red";}

Comment: @mrdeadsven the issue is that, when I release the mouse button, the dragged item does not stay where it is but it jumps down to the <li> under the pointer. This makes it difficult to judge the final position of the green box in relation to other boxes in the list (e.g. to see if they are going to overlap). The green boxes will be typically much taller than a <li> and there are going to be quite a few of them.

Answer (score 1):

You can't style the dragged element directly.
As soon as the drag is started, it is a bitmap copy of what the element looked like at this moment.

But, you can change its style (or classes) before the drag starts, and revert it back right after.
So, we should be able to stylize it to be at the good position before the "screenshot" occurs.

Here is an attempt where the styling works but not the positionning… I'm trying to figure it out:

```js
(function initDragDrop() {
  initDragDrop.dragged = null;

  // Dragged
  $('div')
    .on('dragstart', function(event) {

      initDragDrop.dragged = this;
      initDragDrop.dragged.classList.add('ghost');
      event.originalEvent.dataTransfer.setData('text/plain', 'dummy');

      // Set style for the element before dragging it
      var elm = event.target;
      elm.classList.add('dragged');
      elm.style.top = (event.clientY) - 5 + 'px';
      elm.style.left = (event.clientX) - 5 + 'px';
      
      // Reset style after drag has started
      setTimeout((function(elm) {
        return function() {
          elm.classList.remove('dragged');
          elm.style.removeProperty('top');
          elm.style.removeProperty('left');
        }
      })(elm), 1000);

    })
    .on('dragend', function(event) {
      // event.target.style.opacity = ''; // Not used
    });

  // Drop targets
  $('li')
    .on('dragenter', function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
    })
    .on('drop dragdrop', function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      event.stopPropagation();
      event.target.classList.remove('dragover');
      if (initDragDrop.dragged) {
        initDragDrop.dragged.classList.remove('ghost');
        $(this).append($(initDragDrop.dragged));
        initDragDrop.dragged = null;
      }
    })
    .on('dragover', function(event) {
      event.target.classList.add('dragover');
      event.preventDefault();
    })
    .on('dragleave', function(event) {
      event.target.classList.remove('dragover');
    });
})();
```

```css
ul {
  width: 30em;
  display: block;
}

ul.small {
  margin-top: 4em;
  width: 10em;
}

li {
  height: 2em;
  border: 1px solid grey;
}

li.dragover {
  background: #ddd;
}

div {
  background-color: lightgreen;
  border: 2px solid darkgreen;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
  width: 90%;
  height: 5em;
}

.ghost {
  opacity: 0.5;
}

.dragged {
  display: block;
  position: fixed;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li>
    <div draggable="true">
      Take Me
    </div>
  </li>
  <li></li>
</ul>
<ul class="small">
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li>
    <div draggable="true">
      Take Me too
    </div>
  </li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks!

 I had tried something similar (without the "unstyling" afterwards, that's clever) but it still is not ideal. Considering also my other issue it looks like I'll have to resort to not using the drag events.

Comment: Hey @FrancescoNardone, I've enhanced my snippet using classes for the dragged and ghost elements. I've also added the position management but… the thing is that the position seems to be not applied at the beginning of the drag but right after ?!… (I've raised the value of the timeout to be able to see the styled element)

Comment: Thanks @takit-isy. I have come to the conclusion that the native dragdrop is too limited and I will have to roll my own.